# More information about CVE-2012-0883 vulnerability

Tags: attacks, known-vulnerabilities

I need  to have more details about CVE-2012-0883 vulnerability published on : http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-0883

Second, I need to know , what mean DSos mentioned on the Overview section. 
 Is it necessary to have another vulnerability which allows an attacker to create an illicit dynamic library ?

And Finally, how can an attacker exploit this vulnerability ?

Answer (score 5):

Access vector of this vulnerability is `Local`, that means this vulnerability itself can not be exploited remotely. In other words, to exploit this vulnerability a hacker has to gain access to the system by exploiting a different vulnerability.

Exploitation allows local users to gain privileges by injecting a BackDoor/Trojan horse as a DSO ([Dynamic Shared Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Shared_Object)) in the current working directory during execution of apachectl process.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Always in the same context
is there a vulnerability whose reference is mentioned at the CVE, that allows an attacker to access remotely and gain local acess to the Apache web server, in order to    exploit CVE-2012-0883.

Comment: The other vulnerability could be anything, a vulnerability either on Apache or on any other network service that can be exploited from internet or local network. It could be any means of getting access to the system, then exploit this one.

Comment: my objective is to gain access to the Apache web server which allows me to exploit CVE-2012-0883. indeed,i have a server web in the DMZ zone of my system. my objective is that an attacker gain remotely access to the server web and then exploit  CVE-2012-0883 but the problem is that when visiting http://www.cvedetails.com i can't find a vulnerability which allows me accessing the web server remotely. the first vulnerability that i will use must be mentioned in the NVD.

Comment: If you want to gain access to the web server then you must first find an vulnerability on the server that allows remote exploitation and code execution. Go through this list - http://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/45/Apache.html

Out of many of the possible explications NVD cannot consider any one vulnerability to be prerequisite to this vulnerability. Rarely that happens.

Comment: By visiting cvedetails.com/vendor/45/Apache.html   , i have found the CVE-2011-3368 vulnerability . Do you think that it is a good example that allows remote exploitation of Apache server , is it possible then, to exploit CVE-2011-3368

Comment: Depends on what apache version are you using, based on windows or linux. And most importantly if the server is vulnerable to any of such remote executions. Run a good vulnerability scanner against the server to find out. Take a look at http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-0391 and http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-0392

Comment: thanks for responding ,i have look at cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-0391 , Unfortunately this can't help me because i must find vulnerability for Apach and exactly for HTTp server vendor , for me the version is not important because CVE-2011-3368 affect all versions of Apach until the latest which is the 2.4.2 . the objective is finding only one vulnerability , the version isn't important. Thank you for helping, the discussion was very useful